# SASS: Invalid @import: expected end of line, was ";" - sometimes

Tags: sass

I've got a sass file that only contains import statements

```
@import "this";
@import "that";
```

if I run sass from the command line everything's good

```
bundle exec sass foo.scss:foo.css
```

If, however I run it from within a script (also via bundle exec) it gets upset about those semicolons. This...

```
template = File.read("foundation.scss")
sass_engine = Sass::Engine.new(template)
sass_output = sass_engine.render
```

...produces the following on the sass_engine.render call:

```
(sass):1: Invalid @import: expected end of line, was ";". (Sass::SyntaxError)
```

if i get rid of the semicolons then the situation is reversed. It complains on the command line and not in the script.

What's going on, and how do I get it to accept the semicolons when run from a script?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The difference is that the Sass command line program notices the "scss" extension and parses the file as SCSS instead of traditional Sass. When doing it programatically, you are starting a Sass engine and not telling it that it is SCSS instead.

So, the error is that its reading it as Sass instead of SCSS.

http://sass-lang.com/docs/yardoc/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#options

This should fix your problem right up!

```
template = File.read("foundation.scss")
sass_engine = Sass::Engine.new(template, :syntax => :scss)
sass_output = sass_engine.render
```

Viola!